# Making Axios post Req from Gatsby JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, gatsby

I'm trying to grab data from my component state and than send that to a REST api. I make the axios post req in an on submit function, however I know this won't work in gatsby.My res.data is "This app works best with Javascript" when I make the request from the onSubmit function from Gatsby. I was wondering what was the best way I can make the post request from Gatsby so that I can pass in the data from the component's state. I have been looking into using this as my gatsby-node.js file however I'm not sure how I can get the component's state data in there so I can use it in the post req. Thanks.

onSubmit Function

```
    //submits answers to backend
   Submit = () => {
    let {answers} = this.state
    axios
      .post("/done", answers)
      .then(res => this.setState({results:res.data,resultsStatus:true}))
      .catch(
        err => console.log(err)
      );
  };
```

To fire the submit function I have a loading gif popup for 4 seconds and then I fire the submit function. Content request is that jsx being returned by the component

```
 contentQuest = (
            <div className = 'results-loading'>
            Loading Results!
    <img src={require('./images/loading.gif')} className='results-loading-gif'/>
  </h2>
            </div>
          );
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.Submit()
          },4000)
```

gatsby-node.js

```
// You can delete this file if you're not using it
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.sourceNodes = async ({ boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createNode } = boundActionCreators;

  // fetch raw data from the randomuser api
//Here I'm trying to change it to axios.post and grab component's state data
//not sure how to
  const fetchRandomUser = () => axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=500`);
  // await for results
  const res = await fetchRandomUser();

  // map into these results and create nodes
  res.data.results.map((user, i) => {
    // Create your node object
    const userNode = {
      // Required fields
      id: `${i}`,
      parent: `__SOURCE__`,
      internal: {
        type: `RandomUser`, // name of the graphQL query --> allRandomUser {}
        // contentDigest will be added just after
        // but it is required
      },
      children: [],

      // Other fields that you want to query with graphQl
      gender: user.gender,
      name: {
        title: user.name.title,
        first: user.name.first,
        last: user.name.last,
      },
      picture: {
        large: user.picture.large,
        medium: user.picture.medium,
        thumbnail: user.picture.thumbnail,
      }
      // etc...
    }

    // Get content digest of node. (Required field)
    const contentDigest = crypto
      .createHash(`md5`)
      .update(JSON.stringify(userNode))
      .digest(`hex`);
    // add it to userNode
    userNode.internal.contentDigest = contentDigest;

    // Create node with the gatsby createNode() API
    createNode(userNode);
  });

  return;
}
```

Edit: 
I tried changing my post request to this

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/done', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(answers),
    headers : { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
  }) .then(res => {
      return res.json()})
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(
        err => {
          console.log(err)}
      );
  };
```

Now I have this message in my console:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api//done' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Could you share a bit of the component that is calling `onSubmit`? Is it in the form, or in a button? How does the complete `onSubmit` function look like?

Comment: @estevan yeah no problem I added some more information in the post

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out I needed to include this in my server file.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header(`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `http://localhost:9000`)
  res.header(`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, true)
  res.header(
    `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`,
    `Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept`
  )
  next();
});
```